# while(true) or recursive function?

Tags: recursion, while-loop

I've been wondering for a while (no pun intended) now what is more efficient to do.

This:

```
while(true)
{
     //do stuff
    if(stuffDone)
        break;
}
```

Or this:

```
void something()
{
    //do stuff
    if(!stuffDone)
        something();
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything on this topic, so any input is appreciated!

Comment: "Efficient" how?  Those do two different things.  Have you measured both for your needs to determine which you prefer?

Comment: Should be reasonably straight-forward to find resources that discuss the issues/benefits of both approaches. It really depends on what you're specifically doing and what type of efficiency you're aiming for.

Comment: I would write `do { do_stuff(); } while (!stuffDone);`. More readable IMO, and all implementation should be equivalent for performance.

Comment: The while loop is better because recursive functions can lead to out of memory error pretty easily in java.  You should use recursion when the problem you have cannot be solved with while.

Comment: Recursion might be problematic unless compiler uses tail recursion optimization (about memory used due to function call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion has the consequence of causing "stack overflow".  Recursion also requires more CPU to accomplish a single loop.  Both methods are CPU intensive, but choosing between the two, use the while loop to avoid a stack overflow crash.

Commonly this sort of "waiting for task to complete" deals with asynchronous topics.  A **Signal**, **Mutex** or some **callback** mechanism offers a more CPU efficient means of waiting for a variable to change state.

Answer (score 1):

**The efficiency depends on a lot of factors**. You cannot say one is absolutely better than the other. Different programming languages do not give the same results. The difference in performance is **insignificant**. You should focus more on readability of the code, and decide which you want to use. Recursive functions are generally of less code lines than while loops.

With that said, I want to tell you that **while loops are generally faster**.

Here are some interesting answers discussion on this topic:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182314/recursion-or-while-loops